# Primes that end with the digits $\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_k}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have been fascinated by the problem of finding certain numbers that end with specific digits. For example, the primes that ends with the four digits 2021. What about in general?!

> **Question:** Is there is a prime number that ends with the k digits $\overline{a_1a_2\cdots a_k}$?! If the answer is "yes", how we can find them, without using a computer?! What are the methods of finding these numbers in general?

**My try:**

For example in the special case of the four digits 2021, I found by Mathematica the following prime numbers:

52021 , 82021 , 122021 ,172021 , 202021 , 292021 , ... .

But I don't know how we can solve this question without using a computer.

Comment: Dirichtlet's theorem guarantees infinite many such primes as long as the last digit is $1,3,7$ or $9$.

Comment: To find them, you can only sieve out small factors followed by a primality test. Nothing better is known.

Comment: @Peter what about the algorithm of finding?!

Comment: Sieve out small factors to create candidates (that have a reasonable chance to be prime) and test them one by one. By hand, you can create only extremely small examples.

Comment: To the OP, I don't think there is an efficient algorithm for finding large primes. I do believe that it is a conjecture that there is a number $c$ such that, for any integer $N$, there is some integer $N'$ that is prime satisfying $|N'-N| = O(\log^c N)$ [which of course would yield an efficient algorithm for finding large primes].

Comment: For any integers $K,N$ satisfying $\gcd(K,N)=1$, I do think Dirichtlet's Thm establishes **existence** of infinite families of primes $p$ of the form $p \mod N = K$. Double check this though. If this is true, then let $N=10^k$ and $K$ be the integer representing your $k$-digit sequence, ending in $1,3,7,9$ that is. Then Dirichtlet should give you at least existence of what you are looking for here.